# Display all files (incliding sub-dir) that are larger than 10K bytes

Tags: linux

I know I should be using `ls`, but there are so many ways to do this thing, right? I'm trying `ls -S +10 k`, but nothing. What should i do?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the find command instead:

```
find . -type f -size +10k
```

If you want to limit to only the current directory level:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +10k
```

Comment: how do you do it with ls if i want to display all files and sub-dir larger than +10K

Comment: Although the `ls` command has options to traverse sub-directories recursively, it does not have options to filter the list based on file sizes, not that it is not doable (say by piping it to xargs, head, etc.), but not just really worth the effort IMO :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -lR |awk '$5 >10240'
```

Should do the job - and it's using **ls**.